# How does white win this capturing race?

Tags: go, tsumego

I'm reading "Sabaki, the art of settling stones" by Richard Bozulich. On page 98, it proposes the following solution for white to settle his stones. The explanation reads "after the moves to 9, it is clear that white wins the capturing race."

[image: proposed solution]

I don't see at all how white wins this capturing race, especially since it is black's turn now. As black I would just connect under after which I see no way for white to capture the three black stones. Am I missing something or is this just a mistake?

Comment: I wonder if there is a copyright problem with reproducing an entire problem and its solution. That said, I fired up Lizzie+KataGo, and they agreed with you about connecting underneath at T15. Instead, it seems that 9 should be played at T15 to win the fight, but again 8 should be at P13 to win it. Also that 6 was correct, so 7 should have retreated to Q11. _etc. etc._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a mistake to me. I don't see a way to win the race. I wonder if the point was that White now has a stable group, so this is a failure for black. White can hane underneath the stone on the right side, and should probably be happy with that - Black was stronger here to begin with.